# How to retrieve unique rows from a table from 6 php files running simultaneously?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql with several thousands of records, and 6 servers that run a php file at the same time using cron.

I was trying to get 50 unprocessed items from the table from each php script, that will pull 50 records from the table, and process them (update a value in  them) one by one. Thing is, they keep getting the same rows since the process takes about 300ms, and in the meantime, the 2nd server is asking for unprocessed results, and get most of the rows of the 1st server.

I've tried using "occupied" field, where I select unprocessed AND occupied=0, and then update with occupied=1 for the remainder of the php runthrough, but still, it seems that by the time of the select+update, a 2nd server got the same results.

I've also tried using `UPDATE table where id in (SELECT id.... where occupied=0 LIMIT 50)` but mysql doesn't support LIMIT in subselects.

Would appreciate any insight on how to split the load evenly between the servers (without locking tables) and making sure each script gets unique rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the rows one by one rather than 50 in a batch, and lock the current row for update (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

You will have to upgrade to v8.0.1 in order to use the `SKIP LOCKED` option of SELECT (https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/)
Otherwise there will be a blocking concurrency between the 6 readers.

Another possibility is to increase/reduce the number of readers to a power of 2 and then make each reader to select only the rows whose primary key is a multiple of the reader's position in the sequence.

For example, if you reduce to 4 readers/servers, then

- server 1 will select only rows whose ID has `ID mod 4 = 0`
- server 2 will select only rows whose ID has `ID mod 4 = 1`
- server 3 will select only rows whose ID has `ID mod 4 = 2`
- server 4 will select only rows whose ID has `ID mod 4 = 3`

However, this will prevent the SELECT from using the index on the primary key.

Another option is to have a separate CRON job (but only 1 instance) which will read the unprocessed rows and equally distribute the IDs into an additional table with 2 columns - `unprocessed_id` and `reader_id`. Then the 6 readers can take the IDs from this additional table by filtering on their own `reader_id`.

Comment: As for mod - if one server is down, the rest won't be there to cover for him, so that's not an optimal solution for me...

As for locking - regardless of the fact I wrote I prefer without locking, isn't locking just between the current session? couldn't get it to lock tables for other processes as well.

Comment: Assuming that you are using `InnoDB` storage engine (or similar) - the above locking happens on row-level rather than table-level. And it locks the row(s) against other transactions - but not against the current transaction. If you perform `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` and then keep the transaction idle without doing COMMIT/ROLLBACK (e.g. for 20-30 seconds) - you will see that other connections will be blocked in a waiting state until your transaction releases the lock on the relevant row(s).